# Low silhouette score yet better clustering result

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science-model, k-means

I applied k-means and k-medoids clustering techniques on iris dataset, in particular I clustered with respect to sepal length and sepal width features across 4 classes. With k=3 using k-means I obtained a silhoutte score about 0.42 and the I identified that the cluster labels and class labels are largely different (verified using the crosstab functionality) . With respect to k-medoids, however, with the same k=3, the cluster labels and class labels are almost similar with only a few mismatches. The silhoutte score for this case is only 0.44. Could anyone explain why this is the case?